# Error in BodyEditorLoader for float and Dictionary , how to fix?

Tags: java, json, libgdx, box2d, polygon

I'm trying to use Box2D editor for my game in libgdx .
I did the Json and downloaded the latest version of the class BodyEditorLoader .
The only problem is that it gives me the error on the float that I can not fix .

[image]

[image]

Link where download the class:
[BodyEditorLoader](https://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/source/browse/loader-libgdx/src/aurelienribon/bodyeditor/BodyEditorLoader.java?name=2.9.2)

any idea ??

Comment: I'm glad to help you, you might consider accepting the answer or upvote? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I once had, to change something in that class but can not remember.
try this:

> return vec.set(rbModel.origin).scl(scale);

think it changes several things including this:

```
public Vector2 getOrigin(String name, float scale) {
    RigidBodyModel rbModel = model.rigidBodies.get(name);
    if (rbModel == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Name '" + name + "' was not found.");

    return vec.set(rbModel.origin).scl(scale);
}
```

.

```
// ----------------------
// Json reading process
// ----------------------

private Model readJson(String str) {
    Model m = new Model();

    JsonValue map = new JsonReader().parse(str);

    JsonValue bodyElem = map.getChild("rigidBodies");
    for (; bodyElem != null; bodyElem = bodyElem.next()) {
        RigidBodyModel rbModel = readRigidBody(bodyElem);
        m.rigidBodies.put(rbModel.name, rbModel);
    }

    return m;
}
```

and this:

```
public Vector2 getOrigin(String name, float scale) {
    RigidBodyModel rbModel = model.rigidBodies.get(name);
    if (rbModel == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Name '" + name + "' was not found.");

    return vec.set(rbModel.origin).scl(scale);
}
```

if you have more errors, and if I can dimelo you posting piece of code that I use, I do not put everything that has changes for my use and may confuse you.

I hope you help.

Comment: is not perfect solution but set +1 in your answer. Thanks